# ubuntu, zookeeper and the pid...where is it - Its needed for monit?

Tags: ubuntu, apache-zookeeper, monit

I am using zookeeper and installed on ubuntu 12.04

```
apt-get install zookeeper
```

I need the pid for monit.  Its not in /var/run but yet zookeeper is running.  I looked in /etc/init.d/zookeeper a d no mention of a pid.

```
service zookeeper status
zookeeper start/running, process 7242

lsof -i :2181
COMMAND  PID      USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
java    7242 zookeeper   28u  IPv6 106186      0t0  TCP *:2181 (LISTEN)
```

Comment: Use `pidof`? e.g. `pidof java` would return 7242 in your case above.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the comments in Zookeeper's /etc/init.d/zookeeper script, you'll see

```
# Symlink target for initscripts that have been converted to Upstart.
```

This means that its the standard script to delegate to upstart. In other words, it just says to look at the /etc/init/zookeeper.conf upstart job instead of in this file.

This upstart job uses `start-stop-daemon` to control Zookeeper but it doesn't pass the --pidfile or --make-pidfile flags nor does Zookeeper create a pidfile by itself. The simplest approach is to override the Zookeeper upstart job (this zookeeper.conf file) to add those two flags to the `start-stop-daemon`.